# S-expression for directed acyclic graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, topology, s-expression

as we know tree structure could be represented in S-expressions. For example

[image]

```
 (5 (4 (11 (7 () ()) (2 () ()) ) ()) (8 (13 () ()) (4 () (1 () ()) ) ) )
```

But is it possible to use S-expression for a graph (esp. DAG)? e.g.

[image]

My second question is what is topology limit of S-expression can represent?

I Googled this quesion and couldn't find a clue, without a formal CS background, I am having trouble figuring this out myself. Please don't close this question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as a recursive structure, like your binary tree.

- You could use a list of nodes, and for each store which nodes it is has an edge to.

  ```
  ( (2 ())
    (3 (8 10))
    (5 (11))
    (7 (8 11))
    (8 (9))
    (9 ())
    (10 ())
    (11 (2 9 10)) )
  ```
- You could store a list of nodes and edges.

  ```
  ( (2 3 5 7 8 9 10 11)
    ( (3 8)
      (3 10)
      (5 11)
      (7 8)
      (7 11)
      (8 9)
      (11 2)
      (11 9)
      (11 10) ) )
  ```

Comment: that's cool, thanks. I Googled some spanning tree solution, still trying to figur it out

Comment: A spanning tree doesn't make much sense for a directed graph. You'd need at least one for every source-node (3, 5, 7).